# How to show correct previous month in react-datepicker?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-datepicker

I'd like to show 2 Previous Months and the selected start date in the center. But if I use `showPreviousMonths` or `showPreviousMonths={true}" It'll receive 4 previous months and if I'll try to choose a new Date onClick, I can`t select a day and instead calendar showing the previous month. Please help me fix this strange behavior. My Datepicker calendar looks like this:

```
export const CalendarFeature = () => {
   const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState(new Date());
  
   const [endDate, setEndDate] = useState<Date | null>(null);
  
  <DatePicker
                     locale='ru'
                     selected={startDate}
                     onChange={onChange}
                     startDate={startDate}
                     endDate={endDate}
                     selectsRange
                     monthsShown={4}
                     inline
                  />
```

I`ve add "showPreviousMonths". Current date is shown in right fourth month. but if I try to mark new date calender onClick show new previous month. Without "showPreviousMonths" calender behaviour is totally normal.

```
  <DatePicker
                     locale='ru'
                     selected={startDate}
                     onChange={onChange}
                     startDate={startDate}
                     endDate={endDate}
                     selectsRange
                     monthsShown={4}
                     showPreviousMonths
                     inline
                  />
```

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FjrBH.gif)

Same issue too !

Comment: Please only answer if you can provide a solution.

If you want to give a feedback to the author question use the "Add a comment" feature just bellow the author question.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34551314)